# How to change shading colors on Kernel Density level plot

Tags: r

My question is on how to change the colors of the shading on a Kernel Density level plot of fish locations in a lake. The KDE and plot are generated using a set of UTM coordinates included in the HTML document. I am very new to R and totally stuck here so any help would be hugely appreciated!

Data:
[file:///C:/Users/k77q645/Desktop/Sample%20UTM.htm][1]

Packages used are: (sp), (rgdal), (GISTools), and (spatstat)

`PD<- Pt_Data`

`PD$X<- PD$utmE_Loss`
`PD$Y<- PD$utmN_Loss`

`PDsub<-as.data.frame(cbind(PD$X, PD$Y))`

`names(PDsub)<-c("X","Y")`

`PD$XY<-PD$X*PD$Y`

`coordinates(PDsub)<-(~X+Y)`

`PDsub.dens <- kde.points(PDsub, lims= PDsub, h=500)`

`level.plot(PDsub.dens)`

`studyarea<-readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Export_Output")`

`masker <- poly.outer(PDsub.dens,studyarea,extend=100)`

`add.masking(masker)`

According to the help box it is selecting default colors that show up as pink to red. I would love to have it in shades from blue to yellow to red if possible. Thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Be sure to list any packages you are using. For example `kde.points` is not a function in base R.

Comment: Thank you, and will do.